# Convert ISO8601 date time format to another ISO8601 date time format

Tags: java, date, iso8601

I am struck with a problem.I need to convert a date in ISO8601 date time formatted date to another ISO8601 date format.For example i need to convert `2019-01-08T09:51:34+0000` to another similar date time format based on the locale.I tried doing this:

```
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(date);
Instant instant = offsetDateTime.toInstant();
```

But from here I can convert to date object, but question is how can I convert to another ISO8601 date time format based on the locale I receive. You can assume that I have the format stored in db which I can retrieve using the locale mentioned above and there is no problem in that part.

I am struggling hard for past 3 weeks with this thing. Please point me out what I am missing or what I need to change in my approach.

Comment: What do you mean by "based on the locale I receive"? ISO-8601 is not locale-specific - it's intended for *machine-readability* rather than for humans. What are you expecting to do with the locale?

Comment: do you mean timezone instead of locale ?

Comment: What would an example desired result look like?

Comment: There is only one ISO-8601 format, you may want to illustrate your question with expected outputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Locale irrelevant to ISO 8601

A [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html) is used for localization while generating text describing a date-time value.

[ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) is a standard defining for defining textual formats representing date-time values that are *not* localized. Avoiding localization is the entire point of ISO 8601, to provide one single format for use worldwide. This provides for easy reliable exchange of data.

For example, a date is represented in YYYY-MM-DD format in ISO 8601, everywhere. The 23rd of January is `2019-01-23` always, whether you are in Montréal Québec, Berlin Germany, Pune India, or Tokyo Japan.

So your question asking about a `Locale` with ISO 8601 makes no sense.

> convert to another ISO8601 date time format based on the locale I receive

Your phrase is a contradiction in terms. There is no [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html) used in a ISO 8601 string.

I suggest you take some time to study the Wikipedia page for [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).